# Box-shadow на дочерний элемент

Tags: html, css, box-shadow

```
<div class="circle">
  <img src=""></img>
</div>
```

Как создать внутреннюю тень у блока в форме круга (border-radius: 50%), так, чтобы она накладывалась на внутренний элемент - картинку.

Пробовал использовать z-index,- не вышло.

Comment: больше кода дайте, пожлста.

Answer (score 1):

Вот:

```css
img {
  z-index: -1;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

div {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px red inset;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div>

  <img src="https://www.burgeon.co.uk/content/images/thumbs/0000241_artificial-flowers-hat-box_600.jpeg"></img>
</div>
```